# ml-workspace persist installed extensions and pip without getting lost with restart

Tags: python, docker

Is there a way to persist installed extensions and install pip libraries for ml-workspace?  When I restart the container the installed packages are lost.

ML-workspace: https://github.com/ml-tooling/ml-workspace

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to persist your data, you must use volumes. You should find out where extensions are installed and then mount them so every container you run can read the volume. If you want it fast just mount /, but you would be wasting space.

Comment: I tried 
--mount type=bind,source=/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages,target=/workspace/cache/site-packages 
but my workspace/cache/site-packages  is empty while /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages is filled with installed packages. do youknow what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know whether it is still relevant, but have you specified another volume / mount that points to `/workspace`? It might overlay your mount